# How to decode JWT in PCL that's compatible with Xamarin Android

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, jwt, thinktecture-ident-model

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution with a PCL assembly, Android application and iOS application, and I want to decode a JWT in the PCL.

I can't use **Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Core 1.1.0** or **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.0** or **JWT 1.3.2** because none of them can be added to a project that targets '**portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10**'.

I was able to add **Jose JWT 1.7.0** from NuGet and verify that it works in Unit Tests, but it causes me to get the following build error in my Xamarin Android project...

***Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?***

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/ the .NET framework in Mono for Android doesn't seem to contain the assembly System.Web.Extensions

Edit: this means that you are referencing a library that was created for desktop use, and has not been recompiled with the Android reference assemblies.   This is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I used a library called Portable.JWT

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.JWT/

You need to do this is in a Shared PCL project though and not Xamarin.Android

You can do something like this:

```
public static class JwtDecoder
{
  public static long TokenExpirationTime(string token)
  {
    var decodedToken = JWT.JsonWebToken.DecodeToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(token, default(byte[]), false);
    var exp = decodedToken["exp"];
    return (long)exp;
  }
}
```